# Friend ostream cannot access private member

Tags: c++, overloading, private, member, ostream

I know this has been asked several times, but I really couldn't get a solution out of the other questions.

So, I am losing my mind on why the ostream operator<< can't access the private section of my class even though it's *friended*.

here's the class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
const int MAX=5;
struct elem { char info [21];
              elem* pun; 
       };


class Bosco {

    elem* v[MAX];

public:
       Bosco();
       Bosco& pianta(const char*, int);
       bool elimina_vecchio(const char*, int);
       friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Bosco&); 

};
```

here's where's the problem

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Bosco& b) {
elem* p;
for(int i=0; i < MAX; i++){
   p = b.v[i];
   os << '[' << i + 1 << "] ";
   while(p!=NULL) {
      os << p->info;
      if (p->pun != NULL)
         os << ", ";
       p = p->pun; 
     } 
     os << endl;  
  }  
return os;
}
```

Error says fila* Bosco::v[5] is private, so my overload can't access 
p = b.v[i];

Do you guys know why? It also appears that I get this error frequently

Comment: I suspect your example is not complete.  Provide all relevant code.    I also suspect the problem is because of `using namespace std` in a header file, and resultant ambiguity over whether the `friend` declaration matches the definition of the `operator<<()` function  i.e. the function that the compiler thinks you have declared as `friend` is not the one you're implementing.   Remove `using namespace std` from the header, and prefix names with `std::` as required, and see if the problem goes away (or if some other compilation error emerges).

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0bda35246161112a) with the code you show. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Compiles well on my system.